# How to take any excel file and copy over multiple columns by the header name into a new workbook (100,000+ data points)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code in VBA that allows me to take any excel file (because we will receive new ones each week) and copy over specific columns by their name (since columns can be added or removed and column names don't change) over into a new workbook. So pretty much reformatting the large data set into a more simplified version with information that I need.

I've tried different codes online but it won't run. Beginner to VBA only familiar with smaller tasks within worksheets.

```
Dim nmary As Variant
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
nmary = Array("FUND", "ORDERED_AMT", "CANCELLED_AMT", "NET_ORDERED", _
    "DELIVERED_AMT", "BILLED_AMT", "UNINVOICED_RECEIPT_AMT", _
    "EXPENDED_AMT", "UDO", "WBS TYPE", "WBS", "SOURCE", "CIP")

Workbooks.Add

Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

For i = LBound(nmary) To UBound(nmary)
    Set rng = sh1.Rows(1).Find(nmary(i), xlValues).EntireColumn
    rng.Copy sh2.Cells(1, i + 1)
Next

' Error after for loop
```

Comment: What version of Excel? This is what PowerQuery can do quite easily. What line throws the error, and what is the error message?

Comment: If the error if after the `FOR` loop, can you show the code after the loop? and highlight the line that's throwing the error

Comment: The only thing I can think would cause an error after the loop starts is if you do not find `nmary(i)`, type mismatch (runtime error 13).  If I run your code by putting the `nmary` array as headers in my initial workbook, I get no errors.

Comment: version 1906. Set rng = sh1.Rows(1).Find(nmary(i), xlValues).EntireColumn gives an error message "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: @Cyril can you show me what that looks like?

Comment: Use Power Query, don't use VBA for this. You can easily extract and reorder the columns you want.

Comment: @BigBen when I pull up the Power Query Editor, I can't click on any buttons

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem was that when one of the array values wasn't found it would throw and error and you put in xlValues for you find parameters, but never specified it as Lookin, so your find was trying to evaluate the find for after as xlvalues.
Here it checks for errors and tell the find function to lookin the values of the cells.
Also, you can set sh2 to the first sheet of new workbook when you create the WB.

```
Sub test()

Dim nmary As Variant
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
nmary = Array("FUND", "ORDERED_AMT", "CANCELLED_AMT", "NET_ORDERED", _
    "DELIVERED_AMT", "BILLED_AMT", "UNINVOICED_RECEIPT_AMT", _
    "EXPENDED_AMT", "UDO", "WBS TYPE", "WBS", "SOURCE", "CIP")
Set sh2 = Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)


    For i = LBound(nmary) To UBound(nmary)
        If sh1.Rows(1).Find(What:=nmary(i), LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Else
            Set rng = sh1.Rows(1).Find(What:=nmary(i), LookIn:=xlValues).EntireColumn
            rng.Copy sh2.Cells(1, i + 1)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```